# Make GIS and draw data on OpenStreeMap

Tags: leaflet, gis, openstreetmap

I want to display all of my data (as point with coordinate or make line with multiple points) that I found on google I see that I can use Openstreetmap (OSM) to get the map layers, but I do not know if I can draw points with the data I have in the database.

Another choice is to use Leaflet but I still don't know how to dynamically draw data to the maps. Do you guys have any example or guide?

This is the code I used to display the map I need to the website.

```html
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=105.82374572753905%2C9.49511711740931%2C106.68754577636719%2C10.14193168613103&amp;layer=mapnik&amp;marker=9.81868236535723%2C106.25564575195312" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
<br/>
<small>
    <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=9.8187&amp;mlon=106.2556#map=11/9.8187/106.2556">View Larger Map</a>
</small>
```

Comment: For showing your data, [Leaflet tutorials](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) should get you started. As for "dynamic draw", depending on what you mean, you would be interested in [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw). Check also the [plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) page for more possibilities.

Comment: @ghybs "dynamic draw", i mean i have a bunch of data from the database then use it to draw to the Map layer. So can you show me how to use OpenStreetMap in website ?

Comment: OSM website itself is based on Leaflet. Have a look at the previously given tutorial. A complete code can be as simple as that: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/18/

Comment: i already read the above tutorial but still can not find how to use it, especially that i can not find the access token from map box. I will look around the map box website again, i hope you can help me firgure out this.

Comment: With MapBox you have to subscribe to get your individual access token. I think you can have some free accounts. Otherwise you can freely use OSM tiles without needing any account, provided that you do not perform huge operations on OSM servers. See the code in the jsfiddle of my previous comment to get the URL template.

Comment: thanks so much @ghybs . i have idea is use turf to make line to the map, can i do this?

Comment: Turf creates GeoJSON. GeoJSON can be read by Leaflet. See the tutorial.